# WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'component---src-templates-category-js')

Tags: webpack, woocommerce, graphql, gatsby

Im using gatsby and in my gatbsy.node-js file I am creating dynamic pages.

This is working fine when I run gatsby develop but when I do gatsby build or on netlify, I get the errror message below and im thinking it has to do something with the path to my template, is it because the path is local to my computer and gatsby build wants another type of path?

I can also see in the WebpackError that its reading from **(component---src-templates-category-js)** instead of .js without a hyphen, is that correct?

I get the same exact error if I import my template with **require.resolve** and **path.resolve from "path"**, aswell with and without slash (from gatsby-core-utils)

```
const { slash } = require('gatsby-core-utils')
const categoryTemplate = require.resolve(`./src/templates/category.js`)

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const queryCategories = await graphql(`
    query AllCategories {
      allWpProductCategory {
        nodes {
          id
          slug
        }
      }
    }
`)    
queryCategories.data.allWpProductCategory.nodes.forEach(node => {
    createPage({
      path: `/product-category/${node.slug}`,
      component: slash( categoryTemplate ),
      context: {

        category: node.id,
      },
    })
})
```

```
ERROR 

Page data from page-data.json for the failed page "/product-category/chocolate": {
  "componentChunkName": "component---src-templates-category-js",
  "path": "/product-category/chocolate",
  "result": {
    "pageContext": {
      "category": "dGVybTo1OQ=="
    }
  },
  "staticQueryHashes": [
    "3971950002"
  ]
}

failed Building static HTML for pages - 4.746s                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                            
 ERROR #95313 

Building static HTML failed for path "/product-category/chocolate"

WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'component---src-templates-category-js')
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is working fine when I run gatsby develop but when I do gatsby
> build or on netlify, I get the errror message below and im thinking it
> has to do something with the path to my template

This makes sense as long as Netlify throws a `gatsby build`, so if a build is failing locally it will probably fail in Netlify.

Regarding the issue, I don't know why you are using `slash` (`const { slash } = require('gatsby-core-utils')`). Have you tried something simpler like:

```
const path = require("path")

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;
  const categoryTemplate = path.resolve(`./src/templates/category.js`);

  const queryCategories = await graphql(`
    query AllCategories {
      allWpProductCategory {
        nodes {
          id
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  queryCategories.data.allWpProductCategory.nodes.forEach((node) => {
    createPage({
      path: `/product-category/${node.slug}`,
      component: categoryTemplate,
      context: {
        category: node.id,
      },
    });
  });
};
```

Note the removal of the `slash` and the use of `path` in `` path.resolve(`./src/templates/category.js`) ``.